# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array [WP Plugin - Event Booking Pro]

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

***Warning:*** array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /data03/virt73559/domeenid/www.traagel.com/maarahvalaat/maarahvalaat/wp-content/plugins/eventBookingPro/EbpSettings.php on line 416

I purchased [Event Booking Pro - WP Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/event-booking-pro-wp-plugin-paypal-or-offline/5543552?_ga=2.121090817.845239259.1578937551-1004848104.1561921214), but plugin is broken in my [website](https://maarahvalaat.traagel.com/maarahvalaat/?page_id=56) and
[plugin default text is undefined  (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxrXJ.png)

```
    $textSettings = array();
$settings = array();

if ($sel != null && $sel != "") {
  $settings = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT " . $sel . " FROM " . EbpDatabase::getTableName("settings")." where id='$settingId'", ARRAY_A);
}

if ($textSel != null && $textSel != "" ) {
  $textSettings = EbpText::getTextSettings($textSel);
} 


return (Object) array_merge($settings, $textSettings); }  //line416
```

When i tried change $textSettings to array:

```
    return (Object) array_merge($settings, array($textSettings));
```

Then [Website](https://maarahvalaat.traagel.com/events/) plugin works, but i am unable to fix undefined text problem. 
Help appreciated.

Comment: I have the following [EbpText.php file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpsGQ.png) for undefined text problem: